# Demora ao Enviar Email com Anexo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando enviar um email com anexo, sem anexo o email envia rapidamente, sem nenhum tipo de problema, porém quando coloco o anexo, ele demora muito, questão de minutos, e trava, e não envia.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma que eu consigo enviar rápido, ou se é o meu código que está mal estruturado. Lembrando que utilizo o tinyMCE para configurações HTML. Creio que não tem problema, já que ele envia normalmente sem anexo.

Segue como estou fazendo.
Aqui é a classe:

```
public Attachment anexo;

email.IsBodyHtml = true;
email.From = new MailAddress(emailAdm);
foreach (var address in destinatario.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    if (EmailValido(address))
    {
        email.Bcc.Add(address);
    }
    else { }
}
email.Subject = assunto;
email.Body = mensagem;
email.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
if (anexo != null)
{
    email.Attachments.Add(anexo);
}
```

E aqui é o código do form:

```
clsEnviarEmail email = new clsEnviarEmail();
email.destinatario = destinatario;
email.assunto = txtassunto.Text;
email.mensagem = txtMensagem.InnerText;
if (Anexo.HasFile)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Anexo.FileBytes);
    Attachment anexo = new Attachment(ms, Anexo.PostedFile.FileName);
    email.anexo = anexo;
}
email.Email();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('E-mails enviado com sucesso!');", true);
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho do anexo?

Comment: Artur já tentei de todos os tamanhos, estou tentando um arquivo txt de 90KB e não envia. Já tentei maiores e menores, e o mesmo problema acontece.

Comment: Em qual linha de código o programa trava?

Comment: Ele não informa, ele fica carregando, carregando e não envia. Sem o anexo, em questão de segundos envia.

Comment: Olha o erro que está acusando: [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 100ms

Comment: Você pode descobrir a linha na qual o sistema para se você depurá-lo (coloque breakpoints no código e aperte F5 no Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendo o porque de isso acontecer somente quando é incluído algum anexo no e-mail.
Porém, consegui resolver com proxy colocando o endereço do site em opções avançadas do proxy em "Não usar servidor proxy para endereços iniciados por".

Comment: O seu problema é de infra então, não de código.

Comment: Não sei ao certo Renan, só achei muito estranho isso ocorrer quando tem anexo, quando não tem anexo, não ocorre nenhum problema.

Comment: Olha, o administrador da sua rede colocou um tempo de timeout irreal pra acessar um recurso através do proxy. 100 milissegundos não dá nem pra piscar o olho. O upload do anexo pro servidor, por menos que seja, leva mais do que isso. Daí o problema.

Comment: Eu alterei a configuração do timeout durante o envio do e-mail, para máximo, porém mesmo assim não enviava no proxy.